# sort li elements using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page i have the the folowing. I need to sort it out using javascript.

```
<li class="cat2 lang1">Hello</li>
<li class="cat2 lang1">Hello</li>
<li class="cat1 lang2">Hello</li>
<li class="cat3 lang3">Hello</li>
```

what i tried is:

```
$('#movieFeatureFilter span#selGenre .subMenus li').click(function()
{
    if(this.id != '')
    {
        $('.movie_lists ul li').hide();
        $('.movie_lists ul li.cat'+this.id).show();
    }
    else $('.movie_lists ul li').show();
});
```

this works perfect. but what i need to sort the list using the combination of lang and cat.

ie if i select **cat1** as category and **lang2** as language then it might show the third **li**

i think you got wht i mean. sorry for the bad explanention. help me pls

Comment: how is the cat and lang is selected?

Comment: I have a drop down menu for both cat and lang.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nnqdw/1/ is that what you are looking for

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $items = $('ul li'), $cat = $('#cat'), $lang = $('#lang');
$('#cat, #lang').change(function(){
    var cat = $cat.val(), lang = $lang.val(), $filtered = $items;
    if(cat){
        $filtered = $filtered.filter('.' + cat);
    }
    if(lang){
        $filtered = $filtered.filter('.' + lang);
    }
    $items.not($filtered).hide();
    $filtered.show()
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Nnqdw/)

Answer (score 0):

Seems instead of sorting you want to show/hide items based on selection of **cat** and **lang**.  Following function will serve your purpose:

```
$("#movieFeatureFilter span#selGenre .subMenus li").click(function () {

   /*GET cat AND lang FROM DROPDOWNS*/

    var cat = $("#c").val(),
        lng = $("#l").val();

    $("#<ID OF UL> li").filter(function () {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.hasClass(cat)) {
            if (!$this.hasClass(lng)) {
                $this.hide();
            } else {
                $this.show();
            }
        } else {
            $this.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Check in the fiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/amantur/h49BB/)